# Where is the logic error?

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate the sum of all the numbers from `1/(1^2)` to `1/(n^2)` where `n` is an integer entered by the user. I can compile the program, but I don't know where I've made the logic mistake, and the only outcome I get is `1.0`. Thanks in advance!

```
public static double compute_series (int num) 
{        
    double sum = 0, denom = 0;
    for (int n=1; n <= num; n++){          
        denom  = 1/n*n;          
        sum = sum + denom;        
    }        
    return(sum);      
}
```

Comment: BTW, it *should* converges to 1.

Comment: `1.0/n*n == 1.0` perhaps you intended `1.0/(n*n)`

Comment: Btw 1/n is 0 if n > 1 for integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

You are doing int division.

`denom = 1/n*n` would return `0` for any `n>1` (since `1/n < 1`) and `1` for `n==1`. Therefore the sum you get is 1.

Change your code to

```
denom = 1.0/(n*n);
```

Answer (score 0):

`1` and `n` are `int`s, so `1/n*n` is evaluated using integer division, and is always truncated to `0`. You can avoid this issue by using a `double` literal, `1.0`, instead of `1`.

Moreover, since division and multiplication have the same order of precedence, you should use brackets around the multiplication:

```
public static double compute_series (int num) {
    double sum = 0, denom = 0;

    for (int n=1; n <= num; n++){
        denom  = 1.0/(n*n); // Note the changes here
        sum += denom;
    }
    return(sum);
}
```